# How to join 4 tables to get data from two tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to select all pages that this user has access to whether it is direct access or group access.

I tried this but it did not return the results as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    pages.id AS page_id, 
    pages.name AS page_name, 
    pages.description AS page_description,
    pages.type AS page_type, 
    group_page.group_id AS page_group_id, 
    user_page.user_id AS page_user_id 
FROM 
    pages 
JOIN
    user_page ON pages.id = user_page.page_id 
JOIN 
    group_page ON pages.id = group_page.page_id 
JOIN 
    user_group ON group_page.group_id = user_group_.group_id 
WHERE 
    user_page.user_id =  23
```

I have provided sample data with my schema below:

Page table:

```
page_id  | page_name | page_description
---------+-----------+------------------
4        |  name3    | descr 
6        |  name2    | description
5        |  name8    | description
```

user_page table:

```
    user_id | page_id
------------+----------
    23      |   4
    12      |   6
    12      |   6
```

group_user table:

```
 user_id   | group_id
-----------+-----------
    4      |   14
    4      |   16
    23     |   16
```

group_page table:

```
 page_id   | group_id
-----------+-----------
    4      |   14
    6      |   16
```

Check out here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6MnsujPF8foREq2Cwt8EDn/2

I am trying to retrieve page 4 for user 7

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like this, go easy on those DISTINCT clauses, they are generally bad practice. This worked nicely in a test on the linked page

```
select 
p.*
from pages p
inner join group_page gp on gp.page_id=p.page_id
inner join group_user gu on gu.group_id=gp.group_id
where gu.user_id = '7'
union
select 
    p.*
from 
    pages p
inner join
    user_page up ON p.page_id = up.page_id
where up.user_id = '7'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, your fiddle doesn't have a page_id 4, so no results were returning.  I updated page_id 3 to page_id 4.

I join group_user and group_page so that I can select the user_id and page_id (group access), and then UNION that to the user_id and page_id from the user_page table (direct access).  UNION should return distinct records.

Then I join this result to the pages table with WHERE user_id = 7.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3vqKF2amyFcPvzaFP8hD68/1

```
select p.*
from pages p
join (

  select up.user_id, up.page_id
  from user_page up
  
  UNION
  
  select gu.user_id, gp.page_id
  from group_user gu
  join group_page gp on (gu.group_id = gp.group_id)
  
) ids on (p.page_id = ids.page_id)
where ids.user_id = 7
```